# Canvas image moves slightly to right onload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive

I am working with the [signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) lib to accept signature for my web app. I am having an issue after loading a saved signature.

Assuming I am working with a blank signaturePad, I create some signature and save it.[image]

After refreshing the page, this is what shows up.

**Notice it moves to the right and also seems like its zoomed in slightly.**
[image]

Any idea why this may be happening? Here is some code I am working with:

```
<canvas class="signature-canvas" height="150" width="500" id="signatureCanvas"></canvas>

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas#signatureCanvas");
    scope.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
    scope.c2 = document.createElement('canvas');
    scope.ctx = scope.c2.getContext('2d');
    scope.img = new Image();
    scope.img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";          
    scope.img.onload = function() {
      scope.drawSig();
    }
    scope.img.src = scope.signature;

    scope.drawSig = function(){
        scope.ctx.drawImage(scope.img, 0, 0);
        scope.imgStr = scope.c2.toDataURL("image/png", "");
        scope.signaturePad.fromDataURL( scope.imgStr );
    };
```

Comment: Are you scaling the canvas with CSS?

Comment: Also, if you could create a standalone reproduction of the issue (in jsfiddle/codepen/plnkr/your sandbox of choice), that is always helpful :)